# Confused by converting WHNF to NF in Haskell

Tags: haskell, weak-head-normal-form

In a simple example, converting WHNF to NF by printing works fine

```
Prelude> let x = 1 + 2 :: Int
Prelude> :sprint x
x = _
Prelude> x
3
Prelude> :sprint x
x = 3
```

But in a case, the type is not declared it doesn't work.

```
Prelude> let x = 1 + 2
Prelude> :sprint x
x = _
Prelude> x
3
Prelude> :sprint x
x = _
```

Can you explain in some details why conversion doesn't work in the last case?

Comment: Without an explicit type: `:t x -- x :: Num a => a`. Which can be inserted into different expressions with a different type.  `x :: Int -- 3` , `x :: Float -- 3.0`. Using these hints we can assume that `x` with the type `Num a => a` is reevaluated when given different instances of `Num`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since in GHCi the monomoprhism restriction is disabled, the last `x` is a polymorphic value of type `x :: Num a => a`. So it is not a simple integer, but a kind-of function `DictNum a -> a` which is ready to create a value in any numeric type.

Indeed, `x :: Int, x :: Float, x :: Double` will run and produce  different values. These values are numerically the same, but computationally different, since they are representations in different types.

Since `x` is, essentially, "multiple values, generated on demand", there is no single WHNF or NF here.

Note that if we compute `(x :: Int) + (x :: Int)`, then `x` is being recomputed *twice*: GHC in general will not "cache" the WHNF at type `Int` for successive computations. This is similar to `f 3 + f 3`, where `f 3` is not cached (memoized).

This duplicate computation is precisely what the monomorphism restriction tries to avoid.